# Fail to record video with OpenCV but no errors are given

Tags: opencv, video-recording

I wanted to write a video file using OpenCV (C++). Looking at the docs it seemed really straightforward. However, when trying it in my program (running on Windows 7), I could not do it.

When searching on the internet about potential problems, I couldn't find an example that used the 2.x OpenCV interface or something that relates to my problem.

First here's the code:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("C:\\Users\\Me\\Video\\test.mov");

cv::VideoWriter writer("C:\\Users\\Me\\Video\\test_result.mov",
                           cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC),
                           cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS),
                           cv::Size((int)cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT), (int)cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)));

while(cap.grab()) {
   cv::Mat img;
   cap.retrieve(img);

   // process img

   writer << img;
}
```

No error message is given but the video file is not created. Even worse, the following message appears on the console:

```
Output #0, mov, to 'C:\Users\Me\Video\teste_result.mov':
Stream #0.0: Video: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, yuv420p, 480x720, q=2-31, 22118 kb/s, 90k tbn, 15 tbc
```

Shouldn't that mean that the video file is created? Where else could I search for a possible error?

EDIT:

When using the code above, I also check if the VideoCapture and VideoWriter objects with the isOpened method, which goes ok.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually configuring the FOURCC, FPS, and frame size fields?

Something like this:

```
cv::VideoWriter writer("C:\\Users\\Me\\Video\\test_result.mov",
                       CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),
                       30,
                       Size(720, 480),
                       true);
```

Does that output anything? Sometimes the `get(CV_*)` don't return valid data. You will probably want to verify that they are return correct information.

**EDIT :** Also, I just noticed you're creating the size object with (height, width) tuple. You should swap this to (width, height) as it is the expected order for the [CvSize](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvsize#CvSize) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

*No error message is given* **but** you are also **not** checking the success of [VideoCapture](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) and [VideoWriter](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#VideoWriter):

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("C:\\Users\\Me\\Video\\test.mov");
if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
{
    // print error message
}


cv::VideoWriter writer("C:\\Users\\Me\\Video\\test_result.mov",
                           cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC),
                           cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS),
                           cv::Size((int)cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT), (int)cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)));

if (!writer.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
{
    // print error message
}
```

Do these checks and you'll have more information on what's failing and why.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write it, but I did it in my code. Just edited the question.